# Flutter login Provider AuthService

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication

My application was working fine but after I update the whole package and flutter with the android studio it shows an error in the login section when I login/signup below is the error :

```
======== Exception caught by gesture ===================================================
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown while handling a gesture:
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<AuthService> above this SignIn Widget
```

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read it in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that SignIn is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }
  ```

  When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

  ```
    #0      Provider._inheritedElementOf (package:provider/src/provider.dart:329:7)
    #1      Provider.of (package:provider/src/provider.dart:281:30)
    #2      ReadContext.read (package:provider/src/provider.dart:607:21)
    #3      _SignInState._toggleSignInButton (package:wallet_ui_app/pages/Login/pages/login_page.dart:391:13)
    #4      _SignInState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:wallet_ui_app/pages/Login/pages/login_page.dart:376:21)
    #5      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:989:21)
    #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:193:24)
    #7      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:608:11)
    #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
    #9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:267:7)
    #10     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:157:27)
    #11     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:444:20)
    #12     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:420:22)
    #13     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:278:11)
    #14     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:374:7)
    #15     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:5)
    #16     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:296:7)
    #17     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:279:7)
    #21     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:185:10)
    #22     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:293:7)
    #23     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:98:31)

  (elided 3 frames from dart:async)
  Handler: "onTap"
  Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#0cb65
    debugOwner: GestureDetector
    state: ready
    won arena
    finalPosition: Offset(216.1, 537.3)
    finalLocalPosition: Offset(98.3, 28.9)
    button: 1
    sent tap down
  ```

I will post now below the code that I am getting an error from:

```
  void _onSignInButtonPress() {
    _pageController.animateToPage(0,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.decelerate);
  }

 void _toggleSignInButton() {
    print('_toggleSignInButton clicked');
    final String email = loginEmailController.text.trim();
    final String password = loginPasswordController.text.trim();
    context.read<AuthService>().login(
      email,
      password,
    ).whenComplete(() => IfAdminLoggedIn());
  }
```

Authservices.dart :

```
 class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth;

  AuthService(this._auth);

  Stream<User> get authStateChanges => _auth.idTokenChanges();

  Future<String> login(String email, String password) async {

await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
}
```

is there any solution for this?

Comment: Where do you create your AuthService provider ?

Comment: in a file named auth_services.dart will edit my post and add the lines

Answer (score 0):

Use riverpod package its easier than provider and now with update packages provider deprecated and got too much bugs about (Provider not found)

Comment: hmmm so my code is now not working due to the update?
and the best solution is to switch my whole login/register section to riverpod?
could you please fix my code to riverpod ?

Comment: yes use riverpod because provider now get too much bugs (or use provider + bloc 7.3.3)

Comment: I'm new to flutter, so now i need to rewrite my whole app.

Comment: use this stack riverpod + drift(this is sqlite ORM) for local database and Hive this is noSQL for make app setting like (dart mode)

Comment: and also http/dio service to work with API from internet

Comment: i will do those in future for sure but not now.. but now i'm stuck because i don't know how to move to riverpod.
i think my app is cracked.

Comment: you app is crashing because you use old packages i can help you just install the riverpod and drift from pub.dev

Comment: thanks for the support, what do you want me to do to let you fix it ?
teamviewer?

Comment: let me know how to let you access the project.

Comment: ok do you have a discord?

Comment: yes i have saadalti#6711

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for all providers is to include them at the root of your application, above MaterialApp.

And for the purpose of finding and debugging issues related to these providers I recommend using dart dev tools on a browser and checking out the widget hierarchy and see if the widget where you're trying to access the provider at falls under the hierarchy or not.

I had a similar issue earlier and I solved this using dart dev tools (I was easily able to spot that the provider I added was falling out of hierarchy and was not accessible, i.e. there was a sibling relation between widgets, which I did not expect, resulting the provider to be inaccessible).

Hope this also works for you.